# Create coverage xml withspark submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit, coverage.py

Require to generate coverage xml file with spark submit command through command line.
I can generate coverage xml for python code using below commands

```
coverage run -p main.py
coverage combine
coverage xml
```

Now instead of directly running main.py i require to run it with spark submit, something like

```
coverage run -p spark-submit main.py
```

How this can be achieved